# Does the edge pair order (u,v) vs (v,u) matter when displaying graph in NetworkX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am getting my edge list of a ring network from Matlab. NetworkX then reads this list and draws a graph in circular layout. My edge list looks like:

```
['1,2', '1,3', '1,49', '1,50', '2,3', '2,4', '2,50', '3,4', '3,5', '4,5', '4,6', '5,6', '5,7', '6,7', '6,8', '7,8', '7,9', '8,9', '8,10', '9,10', '9,11', '10,11', '10,12', '11,12', '11,13', '12,13', '12,14', '13,14', '13,15', '14,15', '14,16', '15,16', '15,17', '16,17', '16,18', '17,18', '17,19', '18,19', '18,20', '19,20', '19,21', '20,21', '20,22', '21,22', '21,23', '22,23', '22,24', '23,24', '23,25', '24,25', '24,26', '25,26', '25,27', '26,27', '26,28', '27,28', '27,29', '28,29', '28,30', '29,30', '29,31', '30,31', '30,32', '31,32', '31,33', '32,33', '32,34', '33,34', '33,35', '34,35', '34,36', '35,36', '35,37', '36,37', '36,38', '37,38', '37,39', '38,39', '38,40', '39,40', '39,41', '40,41', '40,42', '41,42', '41,43', '42,43', '42,44', '43,44', '43,45', '44,45', '44,46', '45,46', '45,47', '46,47', '46,48', '47,48', '47,49', '48,49', '48,50', '49,50']
```

Notice that, some pairs are '1,50','2,50' and so on, while the rest of pairs are in increasing order, '1,2','1,3','4,5' and so on. Although constructing the graph is not a problem, but when I plot it in a circular layout I get this:

[image: Ring Layout with 50 nodes]

On the right hand side, the circle ends with 48th node, which should have ended with 50th node for visual consistency. The reason I suspect is the ordered pair '1,50', '2,50', etc. Is this something fundamental with the plotting function or can I do something about it, apart from manually changing my ordered pairs ? The instructions used for plotting are :

```
f = open('Adj1.txt', 'r')
read_data = f.read()
f.close()
edge_list = read_data.split(sep='\n')
edge_list = edge_list[1:len(edge_list)-1]
H = nx.parse_edgelist(edge_list,delimiter=',')
....
nx.draw_circular(H,with_labels=False, node_size=25, node_color=node_color)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your graph is a simple undirected graph, it's not the order `(u,v)` that matters, but the order of your edge list. Apparently `networkx` layouts the vertices according to the order of mention in the `edge_list` ( which makes sense in a way)
The problem can be demonstrated as follows: If the network node `50` appears early in the list:

```
import networkx as nx
edge_list=['1,2', '1,3', '1,49', '1,50', '2,3', '2,4', '2,50', '3,4', '3,5', '4,5', '4,6', '5,6', '5,7', '6,7', '6,8', '7,8', '7,9', '8,9', '8,10', '9,10', '9,11', '10,11', '10,12', '11,12', '11,13', '12,13', '12,14', '13,14', '13,15', '14,15', '14,16', '15,16', '15,17', '16,17', '16,18', '17,18', '17,19', '18,19', '18,20', '19,20', '19,21', '20,21', '20,22', '21,22', '21,23', '22,23', '22,24', '23,24', '23,25', '24,25', '24,26', '25,26', '25,27', '26,27', '26,28', '27,28', '27,29', '28,29', '28,30', '29,30', '29,31', '30,31', '30,32', '31,32', '31,33', '32,33', '32,34', '33,34', '33,35', '34,35', '34,36', '35,36', '35,37', '36,37', '36,38', '37,38', '37,39', '38,39', '38,40', '39,40', '39,41', '40,41', '40,42', '41,42', '41,43', '42,43', '42,44', '43,44', '43,45', '44,45', '44,46', '45,46', '45,47', '46,47', '46,48', '47,48', '47,49', '48,49', '48,50', '49,50']
H = nx.parse_edgelist(edge_list,delimiter=',')
nx.draw_circular(H,with_labels=False, node_size=25)
```

[image: Bad]

`networkx` struggles. However, when we put the `1,50` and consorts at the end of the list ( where they belong!) it plots nicely.

```
edge_list=['1,2', '1,3',  '2,3', '2,4',  '3,4', '3,5', '4,5', '4,6', '5,6', '5,7', '6,7', '6,8', '7,8', '7,9', '8,9', '8,10', '9,10', '9,11', '10,11', '10,12', '11,12', '11,13', '12,13', '12,14', '13,14', '13,15', '14,15', '14,16', '15,16', '15,17', '16,17', '16,18', '17,18', '17,19', '18,19', '18,20', '19,20', '19,21', '20,21', '20,22', '21,22', '21,23', '22,23', '22,24', '23,24', '23,25', '24,25', '24,26', '25,26', '25,27', '26,27', '26,28', '27,28', '27,29', '28,29', '28,30', '29,30', '29,31', '30,31', '30,32', '31,32', '31,33', '32,33', '32,34', '33,34', '33,35', '34,35', '34,36', '35,36', '35,37', '36,37', '36,38', '37,38', '37,39', '38,39', '38,40', '39,40', '39,41', '40,41', '40,42', '41,42', '41,43', '42,43', '42,44', '43,44', '43,45', '44,45', '44,46', '45,46', '45,47', '46,47', '46,48', '47,48', '47,49', '48,49', '48,50', '49,50','1,49', '1,50','2,50',]
H = nx.parse_edgelist(edge_list,delimiter=',')
nx.draw_circular(H,with_labels=False, node_size=25)
```

[image: Good]

The order `(u,v)` vs `(v,u)` **does** of course matter if your graph is **directed**.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this ! This means I have to change my matlab script to generate correct(required) order of edge-list.

Comment: Glad to help. You probably know better than me. The problem of finding the ideal layout for a graph isn't trivial.(for some definition of ideal) correct?

Comment: Certainly not trivial when you have node attributes to bind ! That's the reason, I sometimes prefer to build my own little scripts for specific layouts. Sure, they don't look "professional"..but serves the purpose well.